# Get the number of open sockets weblogic

Tags: sockets, unix, weblogic

I am trying to getting the total number of currently open sockets so that I can check to see if it is over 300: if so, I'd like to send an alert.

I referred to [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/admin_ref/admin_refIX.html), but I wasn't able to find something to get the number of open sockets. I think that the code goes something like this:

```
java -classpath .../weblogicj.ar weblogic.Admin 
     -adminurl IP 
     -username USER 
     -password PASS "HERE GOES THE CODE" NAMEOFSERVER
```

How do I go about determining the number of sockets?

Comment: You should include the relevant information from your link and why you think the provided code would yield the number of open sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Weblogic are you using? In Weblogic 12.2.1 you can use WDLF Smart rules to monitor the "ServerRuntimeMBean.OpenSocketsCurrentCount". You will have to define a ServerGenericMetricRule and set the attribute to the above mentioned MBean. You can find more information here: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLDFC/appendix_smartrules.htm#WLDFC675

If you are in a previous version you can programatically access the "openSocketsCurrentCount" MBean with WLST or Java. Here is a list of available MBeans: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_domain_monitor_servers.html